# Cleanest way to load a BIT into a CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, sql-server-2008-r2

I am loading `BIT` datatype from the database to populate a `CheckBox`.  Currently I have:

```
chkDependencies.Checked = (objRdr["BitColumn"].ToString().ToLower() == "true" ? true : false);
```

`objRdr` is a `SqlDataReader`.

This looks messy and I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to load the `BIT` data?

Comment: Is it a sqlserver database?

Comment: What exactly do yo mean by "bit" information?  Is the field a `bit`, or are you storing bit flag in an integer, for example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Field extension method for DataRow

```
chkDependencies.Checked = dataRow.Field<bool>("BitColumn");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `BitColumn` is an actual `bit` field in the database (and not `null`)...

```
chkDependencied.Checked = (bool)objRdr["BitColumn"];
```

Comment: No - if the type wtihin objRdr is a string, you will get an invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying type of you 'BIT' is a string, then this will work:

```
chkDependencied.Checked = bool.Parse(objRdr["BitColumn"]);
```

If the underlying type of you 'BIT' is a boolean, then this will work:

```
chkDependencied.Checked = (bool)objRdr["BitColumn"];
```

This assumes that objReader is some sort of keyed dictionary typed to contain base-object i.e.:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```